# nodejs эмуляция com порт (терминал)

Tags: node.js, сокет

Коллеги. Ни как не могу придумать как мне сделать эмулятор COM порта (телетайпа). Мне надо, грубо говоря иметь следующее:

1. Клиент. Форма. Поле ввода trype="file". Отправляем файл *.txt ASCII формат на сервер
2. Сервер. Nodejs. Скачивает файл. Сохраняет. И далее, должна его открыть и на клиента отправлять данные эмулирую работу телетайпа, скажем, отправлять, со скоростью 3-5 символов в секунду.
3. Данные, на клиента, отправляются через сокет

Первую часть я сделал. 
Файл сохраняю, читаю так:

```
fs.readFile(filePath, 'ascii', function (err, data) {
    if (!err) {
       io.sockets.emit('emulator-write-raw-data', data);
    }
});
```

Таким образом если делать, то отправляется все. Весь файл. Если делать задержку, что то типа такого

```
fs.readFile(filePath, 'ascii', function (err, data) {
    if (!err) {
       for (var i in data) {
          var char = data[i];

          setTimeout(function() {
            io.sockets.emit('emulator-write-raw-data', char);
          }, that.delay);
       }
    }
});
```

То происходит просто задержка и потом отправляется последний символ, а ни по одному. Может у кого будут какие мысли как это реализовать?

PS: Я бы поставил модули SerialPort. Но он зараза не ставится. Ибо Нода старая. И обновить я ее не могу, по разным причинам, уточнять не буду. В любом случае, тут что то должно быть простое. Заранее всем спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Читай про замыкания.

Так можно отправить все символы, но порядок их отправки неопределён:

```
setTimeout(function(ch) {
  io.sockets.emit('emulator-write-raw-data', ch);
}, that.delay, data[i]);
```

А тебе надо использовать нечто типа рекурсивной функции, вызывающей отправку символа и себя со сдедующим индексом в setTimeout. Что-то типа такого (писал прямо тут, так что могут быть ошибки):

```
setTimeout(function go(i) {
  if(i < data.length) {
    io.sockets.emit('emulator-write-raw-data', data[i]);
    setTimeout(go, 0, i+1);
  }
}, that.delay, 0);
```

Comment: Работает. Я немного изменил 

setTimeout(function go(i) {
  if(i < data.length) {
    io.sockets.emit('emulator-write-raw-data', data[i]);
    setTimeout(go, that.delay, i+1);
  }
}, 0, 0);

that.delay во внутренний таймер поставил. Иначе долгая пауза, а потом выплевывает. Спасибо!

Comment: @ВладимирВоловиков, В твоём коде таймауты были на одно и то же время, поэтому я предположил, что нужна минимальная задержка между отправками и пауза в начале.